# Sound glitch on Android OpenSLES buffered queue

Tags: android-ndk, opensl

I've implemented an OpenSLES buffered queue following the example here: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/master/native-audio/app/src/main/cpp/native-audio-jni.c

However when I enqueue my sound and it's (implicitly) played, I can hear a glitch at the beginning of the sound:

```
(*bqPlayerBufferQueue)->Enqueue(bqPlayerBufferQueue, nextBuffer, nextSize);
```

This glitch is not present on the (file) sample.

If I enqueue twice the sample, I can hear twice this glitch.

The sample was encoded using Audacity into a mono .wav of 44kHz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, .wav format does not means raw hence the file start with an header. That was what producing the glitch at the beginning.

With Audacity, exporting as "Other uncompressed format" > "RAW (header-less)", "Signed 16-bit PCM" solved the issue.